# Conductors of Weil-Deligne representations

Tags: local-fields, rt.representation-theory, nt.number-theory

Suppose $(V,N)$ is an $n$-dimensional semisimple $WD$ representation of $W_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$.  This corresponds under local Langlands to an admissable representation $\pi$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.  Is there some simple way to "read off" the conductor of $\pi$ from the corresponding $WD$ represention $(V,N)$?

Comment: See Tate Corvallis for the definition of the conductor of a Weil-Deligne representation---I think that's all you're asking. http://www.ams.org/online_bks/pspum332/ . Page 20.

Comment: Thanks! I looked in Tate's article originally, but apparently not hard enough... :)